# add multiple objects to an array of objects at a certain index

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, splice

I have an array that looks similar to this,

```
[
    { 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Gill', 'age': 33, 'sex': 'F' },
    { 'name': 'Glen', 'age': 55, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Flo', 'age': 19, 'sex': 'F' }
]
```

I have another array of objects that looks like this,

```
[
    { 'name': 'Fred', 'age': 49, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Thelma', 'age': 27, 'sex': 'F' }
]
```

I want to add this second of objects to my first array so the first array would look like this,

```
[
    { 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Fred', 'age': 49, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Thelma', 'age': 27, 'sex': 'F' }
    { 'name': 'Gill', 'age': 33, 'sex': 'F' },
    { 'name': 'Glen', 'age': 55, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Flo', 'age': 19, 'sex': 'F' }
]
```

So I thought it would be case of doing,

`originalPeople.splice(1, 0, newPeople)`

But when I `console.log` my originalPeople array doing this, I get the following similar output,

```
{ 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'sex': 'M' },
    ƒ newPeople(),
    { 'name': 'Gill', 'age': 33, 'sex': 'F' },
    { 'name': 'Glen', 'age': 55, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Flo', 'age': 19, 'sex': 'F' }
```

I assume you can splice an array objects into an array and I have to do something different?

Comment: Looks like `newPeople` is a function.

Answer (score 3):

Use spread operator to add newPeople (see code below)

```
let originalPeople = [
    { 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Gill', 'age': 33, 'sex': 'F' },
    { 'name': 'Glen', 'age': 55, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Flo', 'age': 19, 'sex': 'F' }
]

let newPeople = [
    { 'name': 'Fred', 'age': 49, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Thelma', 'age': 27, 'sex': 'F' }
]

originalPeople.splice(1, 0, ...newPeople)

console.log(originalPeople)
```

Answer (score 0):

could this be useful?

```
var arr1 = [
    { 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Gill', 'age': 33, 'sex': 'F' },
    { 'name': 'Glen', 'age': 55, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Flo', 'age': 19, 'sex': 'F' }
]

var arr2 = [
    { 'name': 'Fred', 'age': 49, 'sex': 'M' },
    { 'name': 'Thelma', 'age': 27, 'sex': 'F' }
]

arr1.push(...arr2);

console.log(arr1)
```